# 3 ring 3.5mm audio splitter for mic and headphones

Tags: audio, microphone, splitter, 3.5mm

I'm trying to find a splitter for my headset (headphones with microphone).

I want to be able to connect to 2 different devices. I'd like to connect to my PS4 & phone at the same time, get audio from both and use my microphone for both devices.

So a female to 2 male connection.

Does such a thing exist? If it does how would I search for it?

My headset has the usual 3.5mm <s>jack</s> plug.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need something like a small mixer (audio mixing console) for this. I'm not an electronics engineer, but I'm pretty sure you can't just passively wire things up this way and expect it to work. You'd be connecting the output of two amplifiers together. I think you'd also have problems using a single mic to drive two mic-ins evenly, with strong enough signal levels.